# how do i compare two files using a batch script with a count of differences

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have two files file1 and file2.

File1 ( which is the reference file) contains

```
ABC
DEF
ABCD
XYZ
DEFG
```

File2 contains

```
ABC
DEF
```

If "File2" has more entries as compared to "File1" then display the count of such differences and the entries which are different

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490904.aspx

Comment: @PreetSangha FC is clumsy and has bugs when comparing text.

Answer (score 2):

```
findstr /vxg:file2 file1>file3
for /f %%a in ('^<file3 find /v /c ""') do echo %%a differences
```

Comment: +1 That's better than fiddling with lots of file manipulation!  Thanks for the /x comment.

Answer (score 0):

Input files are `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` and the result file is `file3.tmp`

Unsure that the files have trailing CRLF pairs.

```
@echo off
copy file2.txt file3.tmp >nul
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file1.txt) do (
findstr /v "^%%a$" <file3.tmp >file3.tmp3
move file3.tmp3 file3.tmp >nul
)
echo number of new lines:
find /c /v "" <file3.tmp
echo.
type file3.tmp
pause
```

Comment: `findstr /x`=force PATTERN to match only whole lines (doesn't match `ABC` to `ABCD`, like `grep -x`).  :)